# [Unity]How to Trigger random Icon, with switch case?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, triggers, switch-statement

I'm currently trying to make a random icon pop up mechanic like, customer has a random order of pizza.

I'm trying to make a random display mechanic, where each customer has a random order with switch case, and it will display just like how the order selected from the switch case.

I put the order icon as a gameobject array with the size of 3. So when they stop to order, it will activate the gameobject above their head.

Here's how the code goes:

```
private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("OrderingPoint")) 
    {
        int rand = Random.Range(0, 3);            
        switch (rand)
        {
            case 0:

                OrderPicture[0].SetActive(true);
                if (rand == 0 && collision.gameObject.name == "Rendang")
                {
                    OrderPicture[0].SetActive(false);
                    GetRendang();
                }               
                //RecipeObject.Artwork.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 1:

                //CuisineObject.Artwork.SetActive(true);
                OrderPicture[1].SetActive(true);
                if (rand == 1 && collision.gameObject.name == "Gado Gado")
                {
                    OrderPicture[1].SetActive(false);
                    GetGadoGado();
                }

                //RecipeObject.Artwork.SetActive(false);
                break;
            case 2:

                OrderPicture[2].SetActive(true);
                if (rand == 2 && collision.gameObject.name == "Soto")
                {
                    OrderPicture[2].SetActive(false);
                    GetSoto();
                }

                //CuisineObject.Artwork.SetActive(false);
                break;
        }
    }      
}
```

I expected it will enable the image gameobject, but it won't. so what did I miss?

Comment: Looking at your code, it appears that you first do OrderPicture.SetActive in each case, and then instantly deactivate it in the if statement... what is the if statement supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all [`OnCollisionStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionStay2D.html) is called **every frame** so currently you generate and execute a new random index every frame.

You probably should rather use [`OnCollisionEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) which is only called in the frame the collision occures.

---

Than there are a lot of things that could be simplyfied without using `switch-case` at all since your checks for `if(rand == XY)` are redundant and also the hardcoded indexes for `OrderPicture[XY].SetActive(true);` are already covered by the `rand` value:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if(!collision.gameObject.CompareTag("OrderingPoint")) return;

    int rand = Random.Range(0, 3);

    // First deactivate all pictures because as I understand you want to show only one
    foreach(var icon in OrderPicture)
    {
        icon.SetActive(false);
    }

    // Show the icon according to the random index
    OrderPicture[rand].SetActive(true);

    switch (rand)
    {
        case 0:
            if (collision.gameObject.name == "Rendang")
            {
                GetRendang();
            }               
            //RecipeObject.Artwork.SetActive(false);
            break;

        case 1:
            //CuisineObject.Artwork.SetActive(true);
            if (collision.gameObject.name == "Gado Gado")
            {
                GetGadoGado();
            }

            //RecipeObject.Artwork.SetActive(false);
            break;

        case 2:
            if (collision.gameObject.name == "Soto")
            {
                GetSoto();
            }

            //CuisineObject.Artwork.SetActive(false);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. i'm going to give it a try.